# Need help on SELECT DISTINCT query

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm using Firebird 2.1 to perform this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT INVOICES.INVNO,INVOICES.DEPNO,INVOICES.INVN,INVOICES.CONTNO,SYSPROF.NAME
FROM INVOICES
LEFT JOIN INVSPEC ON (INVOICES.INVNO = INVSPEC.INVNO) AND (INVOICES.DEPNO = INVSPEC.DEPNO)
LEFT JOIN SYSPROF ON (INVSPEC.SYSNO = SYSPROF.SYSNO) WHERE
(INVOICES.INVNO = 17 AND INVOICES.DEPNO = 6555)
OR(INVOICES.INVNO = 16 AND INVOICES.DEPNO = 6555);
```

and it returns me these records:

[image]

Please help me to build a query that will return these records:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: How should it know to pick one NAME and not the other? (The NAME is part of the record being DISTICT'ed.)

Comment: Only the first name is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance:

```
SELECT INVOICES.INVNO,min(INVOICES.DEPNO),min(INVOICES.INVN),min(INVOICES.CONTNO),min(SYSPROF.NAME)
FROM INVOICES
LEFT JOIN INVSPEC ON (INVOICES.INVNO = INVSPEC.INVNO) AND (INVOICES.DEPNO = INVSPEC.DEPNO)
LEFT JOIN SYSPROF ON (INVSPEC.SYSNO = SYSPROF.SYSNO) WHERE
(INVOICES.INVNO = 17 AND INVOICES.DEPNO = 6555)
OR(INVOICES.INVNO = 16 AND INVOICES.DEPNO = 6555);
GROUP BY INVOICES.INVNO
```

This query returns one row per invoice and takes any name from the sysprof.